# Carry Forward values in Presto

Tags: window-functions, presto

I am using the below query to pivot my data and generate a CSV but the problem is I have a dataset in which the data points are coming in a scattered way with each timestamp.

```
with map_date as (
 SELECT 
 vin, 
 epoch,
 timestamp,
 date,
 map_agg(signalName, value) as map_values
 from hive.vehicle_signals.vehicle_signals_flat
where date(date) = date('2020-03-12')
and date(cast(from_unixtime(epoch) as timestamp) - interval '0' hour) = current_date - interval '2' day
and vin = '000011' 
and signalName in ('timestamp','epoch','msgId','usec','vlan','vin','msgName','value')
GROUP BY vin, epoch, timestamp, date
order by timestamp desc 
)
SELECT
  epoch
, timestamp
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'value') IS NOT NULL THEN map_values['value'] ELSE NULL END AS value
, vin
, current_date - interval '2' day AS date
from map_date
```

I get the following CSV as a result. Is there a way I can carry forward the value until a new value is found at a newer timestamp? Like in the image below the value '14.3' comes and the next value '16.5' comes after a few timestamps, How can I carry the value '14.3' till row 7th and repeat the logic on the entire column. How can I make my output field look like column 'G' in the image using Presto?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mysql @variable to store the last value, for example:

```
SELECT
  epoch
, timestamp
, CASE WHEN element_at(map_values, 'value') IS NOT NULL THEN @last_value:= map_values['value'] ELSE @last_value END AS value
, vin
, current_date - interval '2' day AS date
from map_date, (select @last_value:=0) v
```

The last part, `(select @last_value:=0) v` is to initialize the `@last_value` variable.

A basic tutorial

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-variables/

More advanced tutorial with additional info

https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/